Unable to start android emulator Win11 Home
I've been stuck with this problem for the last three days. I've a new laptop, an Intel i5 with an Nvidia RTX 4050 and 16GB RAM. I've installed all requirements for Android Emulator (SDK, system images, etc..) but when I try to run the emulator with a Pixel 8 API 34 image I can see the border of the device emulated with a black screen and a few seconds after it closes.
I attach the log when I try to run the emulator from CLI
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 12680
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A)
DEBUG   | Current emulator version 34.2.15 is the same as the required version 34.2.15.
INFO    | Found AVD name 'pixel_8_api_34'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: 'emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator'
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 12744
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -skin pixel_8
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -skindir C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\
DEBUG   | querying file version info API...
DEBUG   | found kernelbase.dll
DEBUG   | GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
DEBUG   | GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
DEBUG   | VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
DEBUG   | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
DEBUG   | querying file version info API...
DEBUG   | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
DEBUG   | querying file version info API...
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -kernel C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\\kernel-ranchu
DEBUG   | Target arch = 'x86_64'
DEBUG   | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
DEBUG   | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\\ramdisk.img
DEBUG   | Using initial system image: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\\system.img
DEBUG   | Using initial vendor image: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\\vendor.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -data C:\Users\rosun\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_API_34.avd\userdata-qemu.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\rosun\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_API_34.avd\userdata.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\rosun\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_API_34.avd\cache.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\rosun\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_API_34.avd\sdcard.img
DEBUG   | Physical RAM size: 2048MB
DEBUG   | VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
DEBUG   | System image is read only
DEBUG   | CPU Acceleration: working
DEBUG   | CPU Acceleration status: AEHD (version 2.2) is installed and usable.
DEBUG   | handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
DEBUG   | Bluetooth requested by guest
DEBUG   | started modem simulator host server at port: 51653
INFO    | Critical: 
INFO    | Warning: 
INFO    | Warning:  (6x)
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
library_mode swiftshader_indirect gpu mode swiftshader_indirect
DEBUG   | GPU emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
  Make: 10de
  Model: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU
  Device ID: 28a1
I0623 09:02:38.035238   12748 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
DEBUG   | create display 0
DEBUG   | setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1080 h 2400 dpi 0
createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU
I0623 09:02:38.273869   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
I0623 09:02:38.273883   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: false
I0623 09:02:38.273886   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
I0623 09:02:38.273890   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
I0623 09:02:38.273893   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
I0623 09:02:38.273895   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
I0623 09:02:38.273897   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
I0623 09:02:38.273898   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
I0623 09:02:38.273900   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
I0623 09:02:38.273902   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
I0623 09:02:38.273904   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
I0623 09:02:38.273906   12748 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
I0623 09:02:38.275908   12748 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc. (NVIDIA))
I0623 09:02:38.275918   12748 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (ANGLE (NVIDIA, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-32.0.15.5599))
I0623 09:02:38.275921   12748 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.17734 git hash: 1bd1a3db1c60))
DEBUG   | Android qemu version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A)
DEBUG   | Starting QEMU main loop
DEBUG   | android_fopen: Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
DEBUG   | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '420'
AEHD is operational
DEBUG   | control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-camera: true
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-touch: false
DEBUG   | goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]
INFO    | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
DEBUG   | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Unknown/Unknown'
DEBUG   | android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
INFO    | Using security allow list from: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\emulator_access.json
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\12744\jwks\40d1b054-25f5-4a29-8837-1d2d57ee9e9a\active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\12744\jwks\40d1b054-25f5-4a29-8837-1d2d57ee9e9a for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_12744.ini
DEBUG   | Successfully initialized Wi-Fi
DEBUG   | emulator_window_fb_rotate
I0623 09:02:38.493609   13384 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2400 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
DEBUG   | setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1080 h 2400 dpi 0
I0623 09:02:38.493838   13384 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
DEBUG   | Adjusting window size by 0.38x for hw_lcd_density
DEBUG   |  no root specified: 
DEBUG   | Path:C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
DEBUG   | Path:C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
DEBUG   | Found: 2 adb executables
DEBUG   | Adb: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
DEBUG   | Adb: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
DEBUG   | Path:C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
DEBUG   | Path:C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
DEBUG   | Window was not fully visible: monitor=[0,0,1920,1080] window=[100,100,409,864]
DEBUG   | Window repositioned to [366,-716]
DEBUG   | emulator window was out of view and was recentered
DEBUG   | config multidisplay with config.ini 0x0 0x0 0x0
DEBUG   | No acpi ini file provided, using default
DEBUG   | added one RIL client
INFO    | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
INFO    | Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation
DEBUG   | VirtIO WiFi: unexpected full virtqueue
DEBUG   | No acpi ini file provided, using default
DEBUG   | VirtIO WiFi: unexpected full virtqueue
DEBUG   | VirtIO WiFi: unexpected full virtqueue (8x)
DEBUG   | setDisplayPose 0 x -1 y -1 w 1080 h 2400 dpi 420
INFO    | emuDirName: 'C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator'
INFO    | try dir C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path 'C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_swiftshader'
INFO    | Quoted param: [C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-verbose]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-avd]
INFO    | Quoted param: [pixel_8_api_34]
DEBUG   | emulator: Running :C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[00] = "C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[02] = "-avd"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[03] = "pixel_8_api_34"
DEBUG   | Concatenated backend parameters:  C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -verbose -avd pixel_8_api_34

And what I receive from the emulator-check command
emulator-check accel
accel:
0
AEHD (version 2.2) is installed and usable.
accel

emulator-check cpu-info
cpu-info:
146
Intel CPU|Virtualization is supported|Bare metal|64-bit CPU|
cpu-info


Edit ADV to set value 512MB or more than 512MB at VM heap of memory options.

You have posted the log that executes the emulator, but the log of the emulator and and why it crashes would be the one that important to check. You can try to manually execute the mentioned command line C:\Users\rosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe" -verbose -avd pixel_8_api_34 in a shell and check the log output.

Finally I was able to run the emulator with the next command:
emulator -verbose -avd Pixel_8_API_34 -gpu host
Hope can help to someone.
